# Python split input text

Tags: python

Thats my code and I want the time separated into hour and minute. Can someone please help me do this?

```
print("Input time in this format: 10:10")
time = int(input("time: "))
hour = 
minute =
```

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: I couldn't understand the question. Maybe you can try to post what's the source string from which you want to extract informations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.split()` -

```
print("Input time in this format: 10:10")
time = int(input("time: "))
hour = time.split(':')[0]
minute = time.split(':')[1]
```

Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for more info